# Add a module/library to meta-toolchain-qt5 sdk

Tags: qt, yocto, bitbake, qchart

I am trying to add qtcharts to meta-toolchain-qt5. My question is to which
recipes/files should I add qtcharts to have qtcharts on meta-toolchain-qt5
sdk?
I need to compile my program with qmake at 
`/opt/myimage/2.1.2/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/bin/qt5/qmake`
I am not sure where should I put the qtcharts. Under meta-qt5 or
meta-myapplication/recipes-qt or somewhere else
 here is poky directory:

```
poky$ tree -L 2

    ├── bitbake

    │   └── ...

    ├── build

    │   └── ...

    ├── meta

    │   └── ...

    ├── meta-freescale-distro

    │   └── ...

    ├── meta-fsl-arm

    │   └── ...

    ├── meta-myqtapplication

    │   ├── classes

    │   ├── conf

    │   ├── DOC

    │   ├── licenses

    │   ├── meta-patch

    │   ├── README.md

    │   ├── recipes-apps

    │   ├── recipes-bsp

    │   ├── recipes-connectivity

    │   ├── recipes-core

    │   ├── recipes-kernel

    │   └── recipes-qt

    ├── meta-openembedded

    │   └── ...

    ├── meta-poky

    │   └── ...

    ├── meta-qt5

    │   ├── classes

    │   ├── conf

    │   ├── COPYING.MIT

    │   ├── files

    │   ├── lib

    │   ├── licenses

    │   ├── README

    │   ├── recipes-connectivity

    │   ├── recipes-devtools

    │   └── recipes-qt

    ├── meta-selftest

    ├── meta-skeleton

    ├── meta-yocto

    ├── meta-yocto-bsp
```

Comment: Maybe with `TOOLCHAIN_TARGET_TASK_append  = " qtcharts-dev"` ?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, In Yocto/Bitbake while You are using **meta-toolchain-qt5** recipe for generating SDK, You need to apply *qtcharts* as *nativesdk* package into [nativesdk-packagegroup-qt5-toolchain-host.bb](https://github.com/meta-qt5/meta-qt5/blob/master/recipes-qt/packagegroups/nativesdk-packagegroup-qt5-toolchain-host.bb) recipe, moving recipe to another localisation like *poky/* will not apply them as [rdepends](http://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/latest/bitbake-user-manual/bitbake-user-manual.html#var-RDEPENDS) package.

I see that *qtcharts* recipe is not available as *nativesdk* package, so You can extend [BBCLASSEXTEND](http://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/latest/bitbake-user-manual/bitbake-user-manual.html#var-BBCLASSEXTEND) variable for this purpose, or use [nativesdk](http://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/2.4.1/mega-manual/mega-manual.html#ref-classes-nativesdk) class file.